# Powershell: How to populate -ArgumentList from contents of a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am attempting to run "gvim" with many arguments and I would like to populate its argument with a command in powershell such as the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\Tools\tests\program -Filter *test.xml-Recurse | Format-Wide -Property FullName -Column 1 > out.txt
```

I have put the result in out.txt however how do I run gvim with the contents of out.txt?

```
Start-Process gvim.exe -ArgumentList ????
```

If I pass out.txt in the Argument list it opens it but what I want is the contents of it to be passed in as arguments and not the actual file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-Content` will return a string array (one string per line in the file). You can supply the arguments like so:

```
Start-Process gvim.exe -ArgumentList @(Get-Content .\out.txt |Where{$_.Trim()})
```

(`Where` added to remove empty lines read from the file).
Or you can skip the file entirely:

```
Start-Process gvim.exe -ArgumentList @(Get-ChildItem -Path .\Tools\tests\program -Filter *test.xml -Recurse | Select -Expand FullName)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I get this error message: Start-Process : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ArgumentList'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:34
+ start-process gvim -ArgumentList @(Get-Content .\out.txt)
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Comment: however the @(Get-Content .\out.txt) does return a whole load of strings

Comment: @Har `Format-Wide` adds some extra spaces before and after the list. Use `Select -Expand` (like in my example) instead, when you generate the file

Comment: I managed to run it but now have the following error: Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The filename or extension is too long. Does it mean that the argumentlist is too long?

Comment: If I do the following command it seems to work: Start-Process gvim.exe -ArgumentList @(Get-Content .\out.txt |Where{$_.Trim()})[0], Could you please explain what the @ does?

Comment: `@()` just makes sure that the output is an array, rather than a single object. When you add `[0]`, you're selecting only the first item in the array, so if `out.txt` contains `1.xml`, `2.xml` and `3.xml`, only "1.xml" will be passed in ArgumentList

Comment: Thanks it seems to be working, I think the problem is the upper limit of windows, it seems that the ArgumentList has a fixed size which I am exceeding by performing that command.